# Unexpected behavior of QDoubleValidator using PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, qlineedit

I am trying to use QDoubleValidator in an application to validate float numbers in the range 0.00  to 99.99 that are enter in a QLineEdit widget. For that I use a structure like the following:

```py
self.e2 = QLineEdit()
self.e2.setValidator(QDoubleValidator(0.00,99.99,2))
<mode code> 
self.e2.editingFinished.connect(self.__call_float)
```

I expect that the function __call_float would be called whenever the the input is in this range 0.00, 99.99 and has 2  decimals or less.

The result is different. The forms accepts values with one or two integer digits  as: "1.", "22.", "22" but not values with 2 integer digits and 2 decimal values as "22.22", "33.33". There are other values that are accepted as "1.2", "0.22". One particular aspect that is weird is that the behavior does not change when I modify the maximum number of decimals to be 4 as:

```py
self.e2.setValidator(QDoubleValidator(0.00,99.99,4))
```

I do not thing this is the expected behavior.

I attach a complete application as reference:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLineEdit, QFormLayout, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtGui import QDoubleValidator

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.win= QWidget()

        self.e2 = QLineEdit()
        self.e2.setValidator(QDoubleValidator(0.00,99.99,2))

        flo = QFormLayout()
        flo.addRow("Input float",self.e2)
        self.e2.editingFinished.connect(self.__call_float)

        self.win.setLayout(flo)
        self.win.setWindowTitle("PyQt")
        self.win.show()

        sys.exit(app.exec_())

    def __call_float(self):
        print(self.e2.text())



if __name__ == '__main__':
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        mainwindow = MainWindow() 

        mainwindow.show()

        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I make a mistake while writing the text. It should be 99.00. I am editing it now.

Comment: To me the validator accepts values ​​22.22 and 33.33

Comment: That is awkward. It maybe something in my build of the library. Just for the reference I am using: 
pyqt                      5.6.0 
installed with anaconda distribution.

Comment: I am using PyQt 5.10.1

Comment: I cannot reproduce any of the behaviour you describe, using qt-5.10.1 with pyqt-5.10.1. The version you are using is nearly two years old, so I suggest you upgrade.